# automatic instances vs new - creating object c++

Tags: c++

it is stated on this website: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm

> Variables that are declared inside a function or block are local
>   variables. They can be used only by statements that are inside that
>   function or block of code. Local variables are not known to functions
>   outside their own.

Then, in the following example;

```
class foo {
    /*....*/
};
foo bar(){
    foo f;
    return f;
}
void main(){
    foo fooReturn = bar();
}
```

how come when `bar()` returns, `fooReturn` contains a valid object?   is:
`foo f` similar to `foo *f  = new foo();` are both objects on the heap?

thanks
daniel

Comment: `f` is a local variable in the scope of the function body of `foo::bar`, and it designates an object of type `foo` with automatic storage duration.

Comment: think about it using ints, it's easier to grasp:

int a = bar();

bar() in this case would return an int that it had created internally, by copying it into 'a'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `foo f;` is very different from `foo * f = new foo();`, since the former `foo` is built on the stack, its destructor is automatically called when it goes out of scope, etc.
Instead, the latter `foo` is built on the heap, requires manual destruction calling `delete`, etc.

But, in your sample code, the returned `foo f` is *copied* or *moved* (if `foo` provides move semantics, e.g. move constructor), out of the function `bar()`. So you have a valid object returned to the caller.

---

**Note**
The be more precise, there is an optimization that the C++ compiler may apply, i.e. the [**RVO** *(Return Value Optimization)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), that could avoid the copy or move of the returned `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

> how come when `bar()` returns, `fooReturn` contains a valid object?

Because the value of the return expression (`f`) is used to initialise `fooReturn` before it's destroyed. As long as the type has correct copy/move semantics, or the copy/move is elided, the resulting object will be valid.

> is: `foo f` similar to `foo *f  = new foo();` are both objects on the heap?

No, the first is an automatic variable, stored in the function's stack frame and destroyed when it goes out of scope. The second is a dynamic object, stored on the heap, and not destroyed without an explicit `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

When you return a local object from a function, a copy is created (with a copy costructor). In your example, `fooReturn` contains a copy of the `f` object (local to `bar`). After the `f` is copied, it is freed.

Comment: a copy **may** be created, if the compiler does not apply [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization). There is no requirement in the standard for a copy in this case.

Comment: Yes. I simplifed a little.